# passing function by reference from within class

Tags: php, class, oop, pointers, reference

I was trying to pass a function (from within the same class) by reference to another function for that function to execute, however it doesn't seem to work.  I can do this outside a class but not from within a class: is there a way to do this properly?

```
class test {
  function test() {
    $this->check(1==2, &$this->t(), &$this->f()); 
  }

  function check($statement, $true, &$false) {
    if(eval($statement)) {
      $true;
    }
    $false;
  }

  function t() {
    print "true";
    return true;
  }

  function f() {
    print "false";
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did it occur to you that you're doing something wrong maybe? If you want to pass a function as a CALLBACK to another one, then you don't do it by passing function as a reference. If you pass a function as a reference, you are not referencing the function, you are referencing its return value. [Classic XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Could you demonstrate please how you do it outside a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing by reference at call-time is deprecated (and indeed removed since 5.4):

> As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

[From php's docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).
There's also no real point in passing a reference to a boolean. The memory a PHP reference will take up is, in theory, the same as a C pointer (4 bytes), a boolean will probably be a (short) int, which only requires 2 bytes. If anything, I'd say you're generating more overhead.

If you're passing an object or array by reference to another function/method, you'll have to define the funciton accordingly:

```
function doStuff_byRef(array &$arg)
{
    $arg[] = 'add new stuff';
}
```

Passing a function by reference, as you'd do in JS, isn't possible in PHP. However, you can define a function *not* to return a value, but return a reference to its return value:

```
public function &getPropertyRef()
{
    return $this->property;
}
```

In your case, however, I'd simply do this:

```
$this->check(1==2, 't', 'f');//pass method names
private function check($stmt, $func1, $func2)
{
    //don't use eval, btw
    if ($stmt)
    {
        return $this->{$func1}();
    }
    return $this->{$func2}();
}
```

Or, even more flexible:

```
$this->check(1==2, array($this, 't'), array($this, 'f'));//pass method names
private function check($stmt, array $func1, array $func2)
{
    //don't use eval, btw
    if ($stmt)
    {
        return call_user_func_array($func1);
    }
    return call_user_func_array($func2);
}
```

I suppose, if you have PHP >= 5.3, you could use a closure instance:

```
private function check($stmt, Closure &$func1, Closure &$func2)
{
    return $stmt ? $func1() : $func2();
}
```

Then, you could do this:

```
$functionReference = function()
{
    echo 'true';
    return true;
};
$functionRef2 = function()
{
    echo 'false';
    return false;
};
$this->check(true, $functionReference, $functionRef2);
```

But that's adding even more overhead: PHP closures are just one of those things that were added to the language, that *shouldn't be there*. It's creating an instance of the `Closure` class, at compile time, and that object is then being passed by reference. Honestly, the best way to go in your case is my first suggestion, still, IMHO (`$this->{$func1}();`)

Comment: Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @user784446: edited my answer. Also, read the php docs on how PHP references work. `public function &foo()` and `public function foo(&ref)` are still valid. Check whichever suites your requirements

Comment: @user784446: expanded a bit on JS-style function references (Closure instances in PHP), and why I wouldn't use them in this particular case

Comment: Thanks for this! With regards to the example using call_user_func_array, the message is printed twice for some reason, thereby giving the impression that it is somehow called twice.  I've only called the function once.

Comment: Ah, my bad: was using a function with the same name as the class.

Comment: @user784446: to quote the flying spaghetti-monster: _"That's what you get for writing PHP4-style objects"_ :P